# AngularJS: apply function after model loads

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I print a dataset i obtain from a service in a list. That's ok.

So, i have two functions, *paint_other_avatars()* and *paint_more_participants()*, (they are http calls) in each item to get some realated data.

My problem is AngularJS won't render the list until **all** the data is fetched, so the page takes very much to load. I want to avoid that delay.

Initially, I planned enhance my SQL query to get all the needed data with a sole call, but now i think so many calls aren't so bad if i would do them asyncronously or render the list *before* this secondary calls.

I know one of my problems is setting the calls in *ng-init()*, but i don't know any directive like *ng-after()*

This is my code simplified:

```
<li ng-repeat="plan in plans | orderBy:get_timing" ng-animate=" 'animate' " ng-class="status(plan)">
  <div class="desc_plan">
    <span class="gris_24">{{plan.title}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="asistentes">
    <span id="other_avatars_{{plan.id}}" ng-init="paint_other_avatars(plan)"></span>
    <span id="more_participants_{{plan.id}}" ng-init="paint_more_participants(plan)" class="asistentes_mas"></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

### EDIT for j_walker_dev:

hmmmm I am trying your solution but i have found a problem
i have

```
$scope.plans = Plan.query({token: token});
```

i guess this type of calls are asynchronous, so if i put

```
angular.forEach($scope.plans, function(plan) {
  $scope.paint_other_avatars(plan);
  $scope.paint_more_participants(plan);
});
```

the program is not entering in the forEach because it has not time to do it. maybe so?

Comment: To help with async issues i usually just do watches. I edited my answer below. Basically just watch "plans" and once its array has the plans, run your function. You could also do it in the callback if you would like. If you do it in the watch, it will run every time "plans" change, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each iteration in the ng-repeat you are making two separate http calls? i think your problem lies there. Usually making any kind of web calls in a loop is a bad practice idea. Huge performance hit.

I suggest first to figure out a better design pattern to get the data without making separate calls for each. But if you must you could separate the requests from the view layer into your javascript controller.

What i mean is make your initial call to get plans. And then do a for loop over them in javascript and call paint_other_avatars and paint_more_participants in that loop. This way the async calls have no relation to the template rendering and does not slow down, once the plans load, your html will render. While in the background you are making your other calls for paint_other_avatars and paint_more_participants.

```
$scope.$watch('plans', function(newValue, oldValue) {

    if (newValue.length) {
        _.each(plans, function(plan) {
            paint_other_avatars(plan);
            paint_more_participants(plan);
        })      
    }

})
```

I dont know what your two function calls are doing, but will this work in making your template load faster?

To

Answer (score 1):

well, fortunately seems query() function accepts callback.
so i solved it this way

```
Plan.query({token: $cookies.ouap_token}, function(result){
  $scope.plans = result;
  angular.forEach($scope.plans, function(plan) {
  $scope.paint_other_avatars(plan);
  $scope.paint_more_participants(plan);
 });
});
```

on the other hand, I am not sure this way is faster :/